# objective c memory and mutable copy

Tags: objective-c, memory

I have a MutableDictionay and I need a copy of all the keys.  I'm not sure if I own this. I am copying it via mutableCopy, but I'm not sure what the correct call is in this situation...

The NSMutableDictionary(myDictionary) is an iVar in a UIViewController.

```
self.myDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary]allc]init];

 //...Add some values and keys to myDictionary....
 //...Then get all the keys.....

NSArray *allKeys = [[myDictionary allKeys]mtableCopy];
```

Now do I own allKeys? I'm not sure here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSMutableCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSMutableCopying/mutableCopyWithZone%3a), "The returned object is implicitly retained by the sender, which is responsible for releasing it. The copy returned is mutable whether the original is mutable or not.". So yes, you now own `allKeys` and are responsible for releasing it.

Comment: OH Boy, I feel kind of dumb, Now that you pointed that it was right there in the Docs all along.  Thank You...